# RPI_Cam_Web No Credential Request

Tags: camera, pi-3b+, web

Re-installed RPi_Cam_Web_Interface using ./install.sh with new port number, username ,and password.  MS Edge browser loads page, but without the html selection and no credentials dialog box, so I cannot get to the camera stream. Subsequent ./install.sh with new port number but no username and no password works fine with all page selections available and camera stream and all options available.

Comment: What is `RPi_Cam_Web_Interface`. Where did you get it?

Comment: What you are talking about? What is the question?

Comment: Question is how to fix no credentials request (username and password dialog box) on PC browser when username and password are defined during RPi_Cam_Web_Interface install, and therefore cannot get to camera stream.

Comment: RPi_Cam_Web_Interface can be accessed at https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!  You must append /html to ipaddress:port when entering url on your browser.  The login credentials (username, password) dialog box then appears.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.